# Function that returns SETOF record in java = error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I must use PostgreSQL but I have a little problem when I try to read a function in Java.

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tiena.RecursosData7(x text, OUT id text, OUT valor text)RETURNS SETOF record
AS
'
    SELECT recursodc.idrecursodc, recursodc.valorfonte
    FROM tiena.recursodc
    WHERE valorfonte=$1;
'
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Then in Java I'm trying to read the function this way:

```
try {
    if (AbrirConexao()) {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        proc = conn.prepareCall("{ call tiena.recursosdata7(?,?, ?)}");
        proc.setString(1,"IG - SP");
        proc.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        proc.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);

        //proc.execute();
        //resSet = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
        resSet = proc.executeQuery();
        while(resSet.next())
        {
            String id = resSet.getString(1);
            String fonte = resSet.getString(2);
            System.out.println("id : "+ id +", fonte: "+ fonte);
        }
        proc.close();
    }
```

But I always get the same error.

```
Erro : Nenhum resultado foi retornado pela consulta.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Nenhum resultado foi retornado pela consulta.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:274)
        at LerArquivos.ConexaoBD.RecuperarIDRecurso2(ConexaoBD.java:117)
        at upload_cg.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

I tried to move the location of the parameters, the function and i search a lot but I don't found the solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It would certainly help if you mention *what* kind of error you get.

Comment: It would also help if the stack trace (and possibly the classes) were in a language more widely used by this community (sorry, like English).  (out of curiousity, what language _is_ that, portugese?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bellninita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361911/bellninita), consider using a cursor instead.  Here are example Java and SQL code that has components similar to what you appear to need.  This is similar to the production code used for the same purpose:

```
protected Fault getFault(Integer dataCode, Integer faultCode,
        GregorianCalendar downloadTime, IFilterEncoder filter, FaultType faultType, boolean verbose) {
    // verbose: flag to display logging statements.
    Fault fault = new Fault(faultCode, 0);
    try {
        // We must be inside a transaction for cursors to work.
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        // Procedure call: getFault(integer, text, timestamp, integer)
        proc = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call getfaultCount(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }");
        proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
        proc.setInt(2, dataCode);
        proc.setInt(3, faultCode);
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(downloadTime.getTimeInMillis());
        cal.setTimeZone(downloadTime.getTimeZone());
        proc.setTimestamp(4, ts, cal);
        proc.setInt(5, filter.getEncodedFilter());
        proc.setString(6, faultType.toString());
        proc.execute();
        if(verbose) {
            log.logInfo(this.getClass().getName(), "SQL: " + proc.toString());
        }
        results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
        while (results.next()) {
            //Do something with the results here
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //Log or handle exceptions here
    }
    return fault;
}
```

Here is the SQL that is inside the function (aka, Stored Procedure):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getfaultcount(_dataCodeid integer, _faultcode integer, _downloadtime timestamp without time zone, _filterbitmap integer, _faulttype text)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE mycurs refcursor;
BEGIN 
    OPEN mycurs FOR
    SELECT count(*) as faultcount, _downloadtime as downloadtime
    FROM    fs_fault f
        JOIN download_time d ON f.downloadtimeid = d.id
    WHERE   f.faultcode = _faultcode
        AND f.statusid IN(2, 4)
        AND d.downloadtime = _downloadtime
        AND d.dataCodeid = _dataCodeid 
    GROUP BY f.faultcode
    ;
    RETURN mycurs;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION getfaultcount(integer, integer, timestamp without time zone, integer, text) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the set returning function in a FROM clause of a SELECT. There is no need to use a `CallableStatement`, a regular `PreparedStatement` will work just fine.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from tiena.recursosdata7(?)");
proc.setString(1,"IG - SP");
ResultSet resSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
while(resSet.next())
{
    String id = resSet.getString(1);
    String fonte = resSet.getString(2);
    System.out.println("id : "+ id +", fonte: "+ fonte);
}
pstmt.close();
```